# Flutter fetching DropdownButtonFormField list items from Sqflite - Error 0 or 2 values

Tags: firebase, flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to make a dropdownButtonFormField that has a list of object values from sqflite database. I got to the point where the list items would show up but when I click on one of them it would shout an error
[image: The error]

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Section currentSection;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final sectionsProvider = Provider.of<SectionsProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Section>>(
          future: sectionsProvider.getSections(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<List<Section>> snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData){
              return Text('Loading...');
            }else{
              return DropdownButtonFormField<Section>(
                //decoration: inputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: currentSection.title),
                //value: currentSection,
                items: snapshot.data.map((section){
                  return DropdownMenuItem<Section>(
                    value: section,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.brightness_1,
                          size: 15,
                          color: Color(section.color),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20,),
                        Text(section.title),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
                ).toList(),
                isExpanded: false,
                isDense: true,
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                    currentSection = value;
                  });
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DropdownButtonFormField is missing value parameter because of that you are getting this error.

Un comment following line will work for you.

```
value: currentSection,
```

Update:

I think problem is that you are assigning whole object to value argument, dropdown has to compare value with dropdown list value to check that, new assign value is available in dropdown item list or not.

However, in flutter(dart), we can not compare object directly. You have to override == operator and hascode to so, but we can use Equatable package to compare easily.

i don't know you Section class, so do changes as i make in following sample class.

First of all, include [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package in pubspec.yaml file.

```
class Section extends Equatable {
  final int id;
  Section({this.id});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id];  // pass all variable with(,) separated as i pass id.
}
```

Comment: yeah when I remove the comment on that line the whole screen would collapse and would show the same error with displaying only the red error screen!

Comment: also add snapshot.data output.

Comment: I've included the error screenshot in the original post! and the output of snapshot.data is a list of Section object `[Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section', Instance of 'Section']`

Comment: add snapshot.data output.

Comment: I've included it in my last reply

Comment: This fixes it. Much appreciation :) Thanks